# R reduced subsetting a List

Tags: r

I have a question of subsetting a nested list by names.
I have an example list like:

```
test_list <- list(a = list(A1 = c(1,2,3), A2 = c(4,5,6)),
                 b = c(7,8,9), 
                 c = list(C1 = c(10,11,12), C2 = list(C21 =c(13,14,15))))
```

And I want to subset values based on a vector like `lnames <-
 c('c','C2','C21')`. The way I can think of doing this is using:

```
exp_str <- paste0('test_list','$',paste0(lnames, collapse = '$'))
eval(parse(text = exp_str))
```

But this seems a little be clunky to me. I am just wondering if there's a functional way to do this like using `reduce` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
test_list[[lnames]]
# [1] 13 14 15
```

This is somewhat cryptically described in the `?Extract` help page.

> `[[` can be applied recursively to lists, so that if the single index `i` is a vector of length `p`, `alist[[i]]` is equivalent to `alist[[i1]]...[[ip]]` providing all but the final indexing results in a list.

Comment: Many thanks, I did not know '[[' can recursively subset list before. But I am still wondering is there a function like reduce(my_list, fun, lnames) can do the same thing?

Comment: If you really insist on a reduce type solution, you can do `Reduce("[[", lnames, init=test_list)`